# What is the correct tuck pointing mortar ratio for a 1907, St louis brick main support column in basement. Lime? Portland? Sand? Water?

Tags: structural, brick, mortar, support, lime

The owner believes the bricks are softer bricks due to the age of the house.  All the research i have done say's after 1900 most houses in this area used Portland cement, lime, and a sand mix.  I just trying to fix there columns for them without replacing them.  trying to figure correct mortar for this task?  any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What type of mortar should be used for small mortar repair on a 100 year old house?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/174506/what-type-of-mortar-should-be-used-for-small-mortar-repair-on-a-100-year-old-hou) - it comes in a bag with the letter *S* or *N* iirc. No idea what the ratios are.

Comment: Are these columns interior?